# Workflow stops responding when list item is updated programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow

I have a workflow running on an item in a list.  The workflow has an OnWorkflowItemChanged activity sitting within a While activity.  I know that the workflow enters the While loop, and if I update the item through the UI, it fires the OnWorkflowItemChanged activity.  However, if I update the item programmatically (through a console application), it not only does NOT fire the OnWorkflowItemChanged activity, but it stops responding to updates through the UI as well.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there a way to update the list item programmatically and have the workflow both respond to the event and continue responding to future events?

edit:  It works fine if I use the Lists web service to update the item.  Why does it mess up if I use the object model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to make the events fire is to use the Lists Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

I know when updating a list item through the object model in an event receiver you can call  SPEventReceiverBase.DisableEventFiring(), etc.  [SPEventReceiverBase.DisableEventFiring()](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.disableeventfiring.aspx)  Have you tried that, or is there a workflow equivalent?

Here's a hack to disable event firing on updates that aren't triggered from inside an event receiver: [link text](http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2007/12/disable-event-firing-in-sharepoint-when.html)

Comment: DisableEventFiring() and EnableEventFiring() are for Event Receivers to prevent recursive calls.  They are not available for workflows or for external code.  Also, I don't see why calling the SPListItem.Update() method would disable the event firint to begin with - it shouldn't.

Comment: added the link i meant to include above

Comment: I tried setting it to EnableEventFiring both before and after the Update, but it still does not fire the event or respond through the UI.

    item["Decision 1"] = "Concur";
    SPEventManagerWrapper.EnableEventFiring();
    item.Update();
    SPEventManagerWrapper.EnableEventFiring();

Comment: you have two enables there instead of one disable and one enable

Comment: I know.  The problem is not that events are firing and I want them not to.  The problem is that events are _not_ firing and I need them to.

Answer (score 0):

Yup i agree the problem is that event is not at all firing. I have noticed that if you reset IIS it works for the first time but after that there is no update.